# Exclude whitespace after last column in two-dimensional nested list

Tags: python, python-3.6, nested-lists, removing-whitespace

Nearly solved, but can't figure out how to exclude the white space after the third column's number. Code below:

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

for row, nums in enumerate(mult_table):
    for column, num in enumerate(nums):
          print(num, end = ' ')
          if column == len(mult_table)-1:
              print()
          else:
                print('| ', end = '')
```

> Your output (is including white space after column 3)
>
> ```
> 1 | 2 | 3 
> 2 | 4 | 6 
> 3 | 6 | 9
> ```
>
> Expected output (should not include whitespace after column 3)
>
> ```
> 1 | 2 | 3
> 2 | 4 | 6
> 3 | 6 | 9
> ```

Comment: what about `.strip()` ?

Comment: Or better yet `.join()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build that string like:

#### Code:

```
' | '.join(str(x) for x in row)
```

#### Test Code:

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

for row in mult_table:
    print(' | '.join(str(x) for x in row))
```

#### Results:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```